# How To upload multiple pictures With laravel and Cloudinary?

Tags: laravel, image, api, cloudinary, multiple-file-upload

Actually I'm on a laravel and reactJs project. I want to upload multiple pictures (album) with laravel and Cloudinary but I didn't find the right solution.

This my db migration file:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('unites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('unit_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('building_id');
            $table->foreign('building_id')->references('building_id')->on('buildings');
            $table->unsignedInteger('floor_id');
            $table->foreign('floor_id')->references('floor_id')->on('floors');     
            $table->string('unit_name',200);
            $table->tinyinteger('unit_status');
            $table->integer('unit_roomnumber');
            $table->string('unit_type',5);
            $table->string('unit_pictures');
            $table->date('unit_added_date')->format("yyyy-MM-dd");
             $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

An this My function in the controller :

```
        else {
            $unit = new Unite();
            $unit ->unit_name = $request->input('unit_name');
            $unit->building_id = $request->input('building_id');
            $unit->floor_id = $request->input('building_id');
            $unit->unit_type = $request->input('unit_type');
            $unit->unit_status = $request->input('unit_status');
            $unit->unit_roomnumber = $request->input('unit_roomnumber');
            $unit->unit_added_date = $request->input('unit_added_date');
            $images = $request->file('unit_pictures');
            $uploaded = [];
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                error_log('for statement fires.');
                Cloudinary::upload($image, null, [
                    'folder' => '/units',
                   // 'discard_original_filename' => true,
                ])->getSecurePath();
               return array($uploaded);
    
            }
           $unit->unit_pictures=$request->file('unit_pictures');
    
            $unit->save();
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
            ]);
```

I would be very Thankful if anyone of you can help me

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($request->file('images') as $imagefile) {
  $uploadedFileUrl = Cloudinary::upload($imagefile->getRealPath())->getSecurePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Cloudinary::upload()` allows you to process a single asset at one time (see [Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload)). For every upload, the response JSON will be returned containing all the information for the newly uploaded asset (see [sample response JSON](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_response)). If you wish to capture the results of every asset, you could collect them within the `foreach`, for example:

```
$unit->unit_pictures = $request->file('unit_pictures'); 

$allUploadApiReponse = array();

foreach ( $unit->unit_pictures=$request->file('unit_pictures') as $imagefile) 
{ 
    $uploadedFileUrl = Cloudinary::upload($imagefile->getRealPath(), [ 'folder' => 'Units' ] )->getSecurePath(); 
    array_push($allUploadApiReponse, $uploadedFileUrl);
} 

// To check content
print_r($allUploadApiReponse);

$unit->save();`
```

Comment: It's okey I just declare unit_picture as json in database migrations and then in the mlodel I declare it as an array  protected $casts = [
        'unit_pictures' => 'array'
    ];

Comment: The proble now is that I got an empty array on the DB Like this :[{},{}]